# how it work Expandable in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, expandablelistview

- how i can make that work ?
- i can separate the adapter and the fragment or everything must be in the fragment?
- please i need your help
  thank you

  ```
  package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;
  import java.text.NumberFormat;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Locale;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.Fragment;
  import android.app.SearchManager;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
  import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.SearchView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class myfragment extends Fragment implements 
  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

  private SearchView search; 
  private MyListAdapter listAdapter; 
  private ExpandableListView myList; 
  private ArrayList<Continent> continentList = new ArrayList<Continent>(); 

  /*
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
  ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
  elv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), continentList));
  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE); 
  search = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search); 
  search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName())); 
  search.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 
  search.setOnQueryTextListener(this); 
  search.setOnCloseListener(this); 
  loadSomeData();
  return v;
  }

  */
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 



  getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null);
  //getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.main); 
  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().SEARCH_SERVICE); 
  search = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search); 
  search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName())); 
  search.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 
  search.setOnQueryTextListener(this); 
  search.setOnCloseListener(this); 
  //display the list 
  displayList(); 
  //expand all Groups 
  expandAll(); 
  return v;
  } 



  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
  getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
  return true; 
  } 
  //method to expand all groups 
  private void expandAll() { 
  int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){ 
  myList.expandGroup(i); 
  } 
  } 
  //method to expand all groups 
  private void displayList() { 
  //display the list 
  loadSomeData(); 
  //get reference to the ExpandableListView 
  myList = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.expandableList); 
  //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data 
  listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), continentList); 
  //attach the adapter to the list 
  myList.setAdapter(listAdapter); 

  //myList.setOnChildClickListener(myListItemClicked); 



  /*myList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

      public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
              int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
          final Country country = (Country) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition); 

          String product = country.getName();
          //Toast.makeText(context, product, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
        //.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        i.putExtra("product", product );

        //i.putExtra("imv", R.id.option_icon); 
        startActivity(i);
      return true;
      }
      });*/
  }

  private void loadSomeData() { 
  ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>(); 
  Country country = new Country("1","heter",1,"im1"); 
  countryList.add(country); 
  country = new Country("2","bor",2,"im2"); 
  countryList.add(country); 
  country = new Country("3","snakker",3,"im3"); 
  countryList.add(country); 
  Continent continent = new Continent("Side 1",countryList); 
  continentList.add(continent); 
  countryList = new ArrayList<Country>(); 
  country = new Country("4","skriver",4,"im4"); 
  countryList.add(country); 
  country = new Country("5","leser",5,"im5"); 
  countryList.add(country); 
  country = new Country("6","regner",6,"im6"); 
  countryList.add(country); 
  continent = new Continent("Side 2",countryList); 
  continentList.add(continent); 
  } 
  @Override
  public boolean onClose() { 
  listAdapter.filterData(""); 
  expandAll(); 
  return false; 
  } 
  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) { 
  listAdapter.filterData(query); 
  expandAll(); 
  return false; 
  } 
  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 
  listAdapter.filterData(query); 
  expandAll(); 
  return false; 
  }

  public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { 
  ArrayList<Country> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getCountryList(); 
  return countryList.get(childPosition); 
  } 

  public class MyListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter { 




      Context context =  getActivity().getApplicationContext(); 
      private ArrayList<Continent> continentList; 
      private ArrayList<Continent> originalList; 

      public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Continent> continentList) { 
      this.context = context; 
      this.continentList = new ArrayList<Continent>(); 
      this.continentList.addAll(continentList); 
      this.originalList = new ArrayList<Continent>(); 
      this.originalList.addAll(continentList); 


      } 



      @Override
      public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { 
      ArrayList<Country> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getCountryList(); 
      return countryList.get(childPosition); 
      } 
      @Override
      public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { 
      return childPosition; 
      } 
      @Override
      public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
      View view, ViewGroup parent) { 
      final Country country = (Country) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition); 
      if (view == null) { 
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
      view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null); 
      } 
      TextView code = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code); 
      TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name); 
      TextView population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population); 
      ImageView image=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      code.setText(country.getCode().trim()); 
      name.setText(country.getName().trim()); 
      population.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(country.getPopulation())); 

      image.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("info.androidhive.slidingmenu:drawable/"+country.getimag(),null,null));

      /*view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              String product = country.getName();
              //Toast.makeText(context, product, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
            //.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            i.putExtra("product", product );

            //i.putExtra("imv", R.id.option_icon); 
            context.startActivity(i);
          }
        });
      */
      return view; 
      } 

      @Override
      public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) { 
      ArrayList<Country> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getCountryList(); 
      return countryList.size(); 
      } 
      @Override
      public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) { 
      return continentList.get(groupPosition); 
      } 
      @Override
      public int getGroupCount() { 
      return continentList.size(); 
      } 
      @Override
      public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) { 
      return groupPosition; 
      } 
      @Override
      public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, 
      ViewGroup parent) { 
      Continent continent = (Continent) getGroup(groupPosition); 
      if (view == null) { 
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
      view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null); 
      } 
      TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading); 
      heading.setText(continent.getName().trim()); 
      return view; 
      } 
      @Override
      public boolean hasStableIds() { 
      return true; 
      } 
      @Override
      public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { 
      return true; 
      } 
      public void filterData(String query){ 
      query = query.toLowerCase(); 
      Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size())); 
      continentList.clear(); 
      if(query.isEmpty()){ 
      continentList.addAll(originalList); 
      } 
      else { 
      for(Continent continent: originalList){ 
      ArrayList<Country> countryList = continent.getCountryList(); 
      ArrayList<Country> newList = new ArrayList<Country>(); 
      for(Country country: countryList){ 
      if(country.getCode().toLowerCase().contains(query) || 
      country.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)){ 
      newList.add(country); 
      } 
      } 
      if(newList.size() > 0){ 
      Continent nContinent = new Continent(continent.getName(),newList); 
      continentList.add(nContinent); 
      } 
      } 
      } 
      Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size())); 
      notifyDataSetChanged(); `enter code here`
      } 

     }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
how i can make that work ?
```

Please describe what is the issue in your code ?

```
i can separate the adapter and the fragment or everything must be in the fragment?
```

Its up to you whether you want to create adapter separate or keep it into the same fragment. That does not make any difference whether you create separate file for your adapter class or keep it into the java file only.

You just need to bind the data into the `ExpandableListView` same like `ListView` which is inside the `Fragment`.

Comment: thanks for answering but i dont know what i must change or add

Comment: The issue is i guess with your `loadSomeData()` the way you are adding the data into the ArrayList. I just do not understand how you are adding. Try to check the size of your `continentList` arraylist. @user3047429

Comment: it was separate Activity and adapter

Comment: if you can explain me with one example plz

Comment: Check out the link which explains the simple expandable listview in fragments in simple way. https://gist.github.com/bowmanb/4052030 Hope it help you.